# how to event track a html radio group

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

is there a way to track using google analytics what radio in a radio group is being selected?  Our issue is that if a user tabs through the radio group (for accessibility concerns) it will fire off an event for each option.

Not sure how to get around this besides adding a button to for the user to say i've made my selection' and then firing the select event off then.  This is not desired though..

**UPDATE - EXAMPLE**

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/DU6s3/3/

**Example code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(this).focus(function () {
    alert("fire tracking");             
  });
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does the visitor select a radio button and then submit the form?

Comment: hi, there's 4 radio options within a group.  They can navigate through any of the 4 options whilst making their selection but then 'somehow' the page needs to fire off the selected radio when they submit the form.  The form submit is a button, much lower down on the form.  It's a long form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use event tracking: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```

Comment: this is what we're using as it happens.  But I'm not sure how to fire off the event when the radio is selected.  Problem we have is accessibility.  When tabbing through the radio options the event would fire for each one, as opposed to only the option you actually tab to and persist as your selection..  I've looked at firing off the event at the next form element outside the radio group but the focus() method fires for everything inside the div,this would be okay actually but I'm not sure how to only get the event to fire only once,as opposed to firing for any event inside the subsequent panel

Comment: you'll need to keep track of it, using a combination of timeouts and storing a value in memory to track if it was fired already or not

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by applying an onsubmit event handler to the form submission, and looping through the radio options and looking for the selected option.

I created a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GRVjh/).

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (){
    var radios = $("input[name='test']");
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            alert("_gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'form', 'submit', 'radio selected - " + radios[i].value + "');");
        }
    }
});
```

Notes: you'll need to update/add an id to your form so jQuery can select it, and probably have to do the same for your radios.

Comment: thanks, the form's submit button is not going to work unfortunately..  The event needs to fire as close as possible to the actual radio group selection...